# Authenticate by jQuery validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, jquery-validate

I use jQuery validation. I check data in submitHandler.

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034377/extend-jquery-validator-plugin-with-custom-method) it's very good but I want authenticate when form is valid and I want do it by jQuery validation not jquery.ajax is there a solution?

```
 $("#signupForm").validate({
            rules: {
                username: "required",
                password: "required",
            },
            messages: {
                username: "required",
                password: "required",
            },
            submitHandler: function () {
                $.ajax
                    ({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "authenticate.ashx",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        async: false,
                        data: '{"userName": "' + userName + '", "password" : "' + password + '"}',
                        success: function () {
                        }
                    });
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery validation is a plugin for validating form controls in the client side, it is not responsible for server side communications like submitting data to server.

You will need to use ajax to do it as you have done.